# Show a preview picture using JavaScript before uploading files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a little script for uploading images with PHP and showing a preview picture before click "upload". It uses an input "multiple" for upload multiple files... So done, it works fine, but I have a little problem ...

When I duplicate the `input type="file"` (and erase `Multiple`) with two, three or more inputs, PHP processes the uploaded files but JavaScript shows the first picture only ...

How can I show a picture for all the inputs?

This is my script :

**index.php**

```
    <?php include("file-upload.php"); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>PHP 7 Upload Multiple Files Example</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      max-width: 450px;
    }
    .imgGallery img {
      padding: 8px;
      max-width: 100px;
    }    
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mb-3">
      <h3 class="text-center mb-5">Upload Multiple Images in PHP 7</h3>

      <div class="user-image mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="imgGallery"> 
          <!-- Image preview -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="custom-file-input" id="chooseFile" multiple>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="chooseFile">Select file</label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4">
        Upload Files
      </button>
    </form>

    <!-- Display response messages -->
    <?php if(!empty($response)) {?>
        <div class="alert <?php echo $response["status"]; ?>">
           <?php echo $response["message"]; ?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
    // Multiple images preview with JavaScript
    var multiImgPreview = function(input, imgPreviewPlaceholder) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(imgPreviewPlaceholder);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

      $('#chooseFile').on('change', function() {
        multiImgPreview(this, 'div.imgGallery');
      });
    });    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#chooseFile` CSS selector selects by ID - that's what the `#` does. IDs must be unique in HTML (obviously, because the whole point of an ID is to uniquely identify something). So to make that select several `input` elements, you'd be best to use a class instead as the selector.

For example:

```js
$(function() {
  // Multiple images preview with JavaScript
  var multiImgPreview = function(input, imgPreviewPlaceholder) {

    if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
          $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(imgPreviewPlaceholder);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
      }
    }

  };

  $('.chooseFile').on('change', function() {
    console.log("detected change");
    multiImgPreview(this, 'div.imgGallery');
  });
});
```

```css
.imgGallery img {
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="custom-file-input chooseFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="chooseFile">Select file</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="custom-file-input chooseFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="chooseFile">Select file</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" class="custom-file-input chooseFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="chooseFile">Select file</label>
</div>

<div class="imgGallery">
  <!-- Image preview -->
</div>
```

You might find jQuery's documentation about selectors is useful background reading: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: It works perfectly!
However, do you think it is possible to have a "<div class =" imgGallery ">" per input?

This could be useful if the inputs are far from each other in the page !

Comment: Yes you could tell jQuery to create a new gallery element adjacent to the input or something like that (instead of simply appending to the single one). I also noted that your script doesn't remove the image preview if the user changes their mind and selects a different file. That's something else you could add. But I think I've answered the question as-is so please mark it as "accepted" if you would be so kind. If you get stuck on enhancing it then please ask a new question with the specifics.

Comment: Alright, I'll check out jQuery to see how to do that. And thank you for having modified my message, I had not read the "tour" page before asking my question ^^
One last thing “If you get stuck on enhancing it then please ask a new question with the specifics.” Do I add a new comment here? Or should I create a new thread ? 
Also, thanks a lot ADyson.

Comment: You should create a whole new thread for that, then the whole community can see it and help you, not just me. In the meantime please click the tick mark next to this answer so it turns green and thus becomes accepted - thankyou

Comment: Huu ... If I solve my problem (like : you could tell jQuery to create a new gallery element adjacent to the input or something like that) Can I post the answer here ? Ty

Comment: Yes - what you would do is, because it's a different problem than the one you asked about here, you would create a new thread about that specific issue using the Ask Question feature, and then also post the Answer yourself - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for information